# How does the name of a Parallels VM translate to the default name in Terminal.app prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, parallels-desktop

I Parallels Desktop version 12 I have a virtual machine named `Cinquième`. Note the accent on the `e`. That VM is running macOS Sierra. In that VM, when I open the [Terminal.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Terminal), the prompt shows:

> cinquiÃ¨me:~ basilbourque$

Questions:

• Where exactly does bash in Terminal.app pick up the name of the VM?

• Obviously there is some kind of character encoding problem where `Cinquième` is being mis-interpreted as cinquiÃ¨me. I would guess the original name is in UTF-8 and is being misinterpreted as ASCII. Any idea where along the chain of `Parallels` > `macOS` > `Terminal.app` > `bash` that misinterpretation might be happening?

Answer (score -1):

indeed it may have to do with the accent, try it without the accent.
my VM is called "PD XP MBP-Lex.pvm" in the mac and in Terminal and not changed.
Do you have the standard language keyboard?
If not maybe opening the keyboard from the menubar and select the US-International-PC keyboard and use the displayed keyboard layout to make the accent-grave.
Lex

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this really does not address my Question. Typing an accent is not the problem.